# Shake effect doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can you help with understanding why the `shake effect` doesn't work in my case?
Code:

```
$('.vote').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body, html").animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        },{
            duration: 600,
            complete: $('#shake').effect('shake')
        });
    });
```

I tried also to put the `effect` after the `preventDefault` but again without success. If i call it outside of the `on click` event it works properly.
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
Html part:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                                <span class="upper">
                                    <a href="#force-reg"><span style="cursor:pointer;font-size: 40px;color: deepskyblue" class="unsigned glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
                                </span>
                                    <span style="font-size: 40px; color: grey" class="thumb-post-up_<?= $post->id ?>"><?= $vote_up ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                                <span class="upper">
                                    <a href="#force-reg"><span style="cursor:pointer;font-size: 40px;color: grey" class="unsigned glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a>
                                </span>
                                    <span style="font-size: 40px; color: grey" class="thumb-post-down_<?= $post->id ?>"><?= $vote_down ?></span>
                                </div>
```

`#shake` div:

```
<?php if(!(\Yii::$app->user->isGuest)) : ?>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right custom-title">
                <span style="cursor:pointer;margin-right: 12px;" id="add-comment" class="button button-accent">Добави коментар</span>
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div id="shake" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right custom-title">
                <a href="http://find-doctor.webbuild.com/user/register"><span style="cursor:pointer;margin-right: 12px;"class="button button-accent">Само регистрираните потребители могат да коментират и гласуват!</span></a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please share your html code as well

Comment: I have created a simpler example https://jsfiddle.net/qoaqw3hg/1/

Comment: Can't see the button in your example. And my code still doesn't work :)

Comment: Scrolldown, button is at the bottom of the page. I kept the button at the bottom to showcase you the scroll is happening before the shake effect.

Comment: scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top syntax is wrong, it should be $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset.top  Check the documentation http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with **this** object use,In your example you're trying to get **href** of clicked link but **this** refer to Current function **animate**. I've create an example from your code try this:

```js
$('.vote').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("body, html").animate({
    scrollTop: $('.vote').offset().top
  }, {
    duration: 600,
    complete: $('#shake').effect('shake')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

            <div id="shake" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right custom-title">
                <a href="http://find-doctor.webbuild.com/user/register"><span style="cursor:pointer;margin-right: 12px;"class="button button-accent">Само регистрираните потребители могат да коментират и гласуват!</span></a>
            </div>
            
            <a href="#" class="vote">vote </a>
```